# {} symbols are making my application crash

Tags: internationalization, translation, cakephp-3.0, poedit

I've got this line in my cakePHP project:

```
<?=  __('Doorzoek {0,number,#,###} foto\'s', $totalimg) ?>
```

Extracting this with the I18n Shell gives in the default.pot:

```
#: Template/Search/start.ctp:148
msgid "Doorzoek {0,number,#,###} foto's"
msgstr ""
```

Opening, translating and exporting to default.po with PoEdit makes this line:

```
#: Template/Search/start.ctp:148
msgid "Doorzoek {0,number,#,###} foto's"
msgstr "Search in {0, number, #, ###} pictures"
```

now, the **{}** symbols make my application crash.

What is the correct way to escape these so the phrase prints something like:

```
Search in 564,646 pictures
```

EDIT

so the problem is the space before the hashtags. Changing the line into

```
msgstr "Search in {0, number,#,###} pictures"
```

solved the problem.

Comment: "_make my application crash_" is highly unspecific, it could pretty much mean anything. Please be more specific as to what exactly happens, and also explain why you do not reformat the wrong output generated by PoEdit.

Comment: 'crash' in like generating an error 500. What do you mean with 'reformat the wrong output'?

Comment: Well, just fixing the wrong output, the space before the three number signs is invalid (IIRC).

Comment: oh dear, that did the trick. I overlooked that completely. Thank you very ### much!